# What do impressions in the Chrome extension developer dashboard mean?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

In the developer dashboard, under stats, we can find two types of graphs: installations and impressions. What does these mean?

Answer (score -13, accepted):

The impressions means that user went to your extension page and reviewed your app a bit, maybe viewed your screenshots, read your description etc.

but they didn't continued to "installed" your extension.

Comment: Its not documented, but if you know google analytics you can track your extension usage with it too.

Comment: Heres the official documentation of Chrome webstore:
http://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/?hl=en

Comment: The closest thing to documentation is this reply from a Chrome Developer Advocate: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-apps/WKLVaktnzxs/I1oi3D4NXRIJ

Comment: From that chain it looks like the other answer here is correct. Impression = on screen during a search / browse of the CWS

Comment: It DOES NOT mean that someone went to your extension page. Answer is incorrect.

Comment: I agree, this is incorrect. 1 impression = 1 display on chrome web store (search results, category listing...)

Answer (score 58):

The impressions are the number of times the extension has appeared in search (both the Web store search and Google). The user does not have to visit the page to register an impression and if the user goes directly to the page via a link in an email etc. it will not count as an impression. This is why my impressions are less than my installations (people send links on Facebook and twitter a lot more than they search for it).

Comment: Hello, I have one query, is it normal for the impression line (blue) graph to increase day by day. I mean, one day [my extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prokeys/ekfnbpgmmeahnnlpjibofkobpdkifapn) had 76, and next day it had 115. Does that mean, on the next day, 115 individual users or 39 (115 - 76) individual users saw my extension in search queries?

Comment: @GaurangTandon The impressions are not cumulative so that means you had 115 people

Comment: why don't any of these answers have a link to official documentation? Does it not exist?

Answer (score 12):

Impressions are the number of times your extension is displayed to users.

When the store wall is populated with items, you get an "impression" when your extension's tile is scrolled into view on the screen. This results in one "impression" per page load (in other words, you don't get an impression every time your item is scrolled into view, then out, then back in again).

Answer (score 9):

Impressions are the number of times your app appears on the screen of someone browsing the app store, but there is more to it.  If you app is scrolled through on the screen, you get one impression.  If the user scrolls back up and your app reappears on the screen, nothing is counted (since the would be double counting).

If a user clicks on the app plate while browsing the app store, you get a second impression.  For example, imagine yourself browsing the app store and scrolling down on the page.  Every app that populates your screen view is getting an impression.  Let's assume that you realize that you just saw something interesting and you scroll back up so that the app of interest repopulates the screen.  This app (or any other app) does not get a second impression from your action.  But now, you click on the app to see it in full screen view. This action triggers a second impression.

Now if you install the app, then, obviously, this action counts as an install.  So in summary, per session, each app can get at most 2 impressions, and a single install.